# guard let: Initializer for conditional binding must be optional type not 'ClassName'

Tags: ios, swift3

I am implementing a static `tableviewcontroller` in one of the `vc` of my app. I have defined `cartManager` in this `vc` as:

```
  var cartManager: ShoppingCartManager {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

`configureCell` is where I have defined the configuration of the cell.
However, I get error on `guard let statement` inside the below function.
I don't seem to have idea why this error is here.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cartManager = cartManager else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    if (indexPath.row < cartManager.distinctProductCount()) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myCartProduct, for: indexPath) as? CartTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell(item: cartManager.distinctProductItems()[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == cartManager.distinctProductCount()) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myCartTotal, for: indexPath) as? CartTotalTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell(total: cartManager.totalPrice())
        return cell!
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: submitCart, for: indexPath) as? CartPlaceOrderTableViewCell
    cell.configureCell(cartManager: cartManager)
    cell?.delegate = self
    return cell!
}
```

This is the same case in my `numberOfRowsInSection` method too.
The code for the `numberOfRowsInSection` function is here:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    guard let cartManager = cartManager else {
        return 0
    }

    return cartManager.distinctProductCount() + 2
}
```

Am I using the `guard let` statement properly or there is another method to use the statement?

Comment: `cartManager` can never be `nil` according to your definition of the property

Comment: "Am I using the guard let statement properly". No. It is far from clear why you are using it at all or what you are expecting it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`guard let x = x` means that the second `x` is an Optional and that we are trying to unwrap it to get at whatever is inside. If the Optional is `nil`, we fail and the `guard` fails and exits. If the Optional is not `nil`, we succeed and the first `x` becomes whatever was wrapped inside the Optional.

You cannot do that with `cartManager`, as it is not an Optional.

Comment: Exactly matt, that was what I missed.

Comment: And as I learned about the answer myself, I was searching for the reason, and I got it from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution on hit and trial basis as I put a conditional binding on the `cartManager` definition. This is the solution.

```
    var cartManager: ShoppingCartManager? {
        didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}
```